# Correct the yml file which just runs the acs setting template once if it has alreay been run

Tags: powershell, yaml

WHen running the devops pipeline I am getting the below error

```
At C:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1698927355304_inlinescript.ps1:2 char:7
+   if [ -n "$result" ]; then
+       ~
Missing type name after '['.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisInIfStatement
```

**The below is the attached yml script. Moreover based on the variable KeyAlreayexits I need to run a template add-acs-value-secured-in-keyvault.yml@templates which I will put after the below task. If the value of KeyAlreadyExists is true then we shouldnot add the value to the acs.**

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Deploy ACS Values and Assign Identity'
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
       $result = az keyvault secret show --name 'A2A:Global_SharedSecret' --vault-name "$(KeyVault_Int_ResourceName)" 2>&1
        if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result)) 
            {
         Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=KeyAlreadyExists]true"
            } 
            else 
            {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=KeyAlreadyExists]false"
            }
        
- template: add-acs-value-secured-in-keyvault.yml@templates
  parameters:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
    settingName: 'A2A:Global_SharedSecret'
    settingValue: '$(GlobalSharedSecret)'
```

I am trying to run the pipeline but keep on getting this error

Comment: `if [ -n "$result" ]; then` in your error message is _POSIX_ shell syntax (such as supported by `bash`), which is why PowerShell doesn't understand it. It is the _equivalent of_ `if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result))` in your inline PowerShell script. Where does the POSIX translation come from?